# Determine order functions are called in

Tags: javascript

So I have a list of functions in JavaScript, each function has an associated button.

I want to know how you can tell in which order the buttons were pushed.

Comment: They're called in the order in which you programmed them to be called.

Comment: sorry, I'm not very good at articulating my questions. What I mean is how do you know what order the functions were called by the user. I have multiple buttons (in html) and when on is pressed it calls a function. I want to know what order the buttons are pressed in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no *native* way for JavaScript to keep track of when a function was called, as this would have too much of a performance impact on the engine.  You'll need to modify your code to keep track of this information internally.  For example, you could use an array to log each call.

```
var log = []; // List of calls made in order

function one()
{
   log.push('one'); // Log call

   // ...
}

function two()
{
   log.push('two'); // Log call

   // ...
}

function three()
{
   log.push('three'); // Log call

   // ...
}

// Call in some order (which could be done by the user of course):
two();
one();
three();
```

You could of course easily *reset* your log as well:

```
log = []; // Reset
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as answered. <3